# Netlogo - How to transfer portion of breed variable to another breed

Tags: netlogo

The goal of my model is to demonstrate epizoochory of seeds when hikers step on a plant.

I have two breeds, hikers and plants. Each plant has the variable seed-bank which is a random value up to 500.

What I want to happen, is that when hikers move over a patch where a plant is also at then 80% of the seed bank of the plant is transferred to the hiker (this variable called hiker-seeds). I want this to reflect in real-time meaning that as plants transfer 80% of their seed-bank to the hiker, consequently their seed-bank is reduced by 80%.

I have written the following code:

```
to go
 ask hikers [communicate]
end

to communicate
  if any? other plants-here with [seed-bank > 0 ]
    [set hiker-seeds (seed-bank of plants in-radius 1) ]
end
```

I am having difficulty getting the model to take the seed-bank of the plant into account when running 'set hiker-seeds'. I get the error:

"of expected this input to be a reporter block, but got anything else instead".

How to I make the model call upon the seed-bank of the specific plant the hiker interacts with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a temporary variable within the procedure where the exchange occurs to track the amount that is to be transferred, then update the values of both hiker and plants correspondingly. For example (more details in comments):

```
breed [ plants plant ]
breed [ hikers hiker ]

plants-own [ seed-bank ]
hikers-own [ hiker-seed ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 20 patches [
    sprout-plants 1 [
      set seed-bank random 500
      set shape "plant"
    ]
  ]
  ask n-of 10 patches [
    sprout-hikers 1 [
      set shape "person"
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask hikers [
    rt random 40 - 20
    fd 1
    ; Check for plants on the current patch
    if any? plants-here with [ seed-bank > 0 ] [
      print "I'm taking some seeds!"
      ; Get each plant that is here to:
      ask plants-here [
        ; Calculate the seed-bank amount to transfer
        let seed-exchange round ( seed-bank * 0.8 )
        ; Update the hiker-seed of myself (the current hiker)
        ask myself [
          set hiker-seed hiker-seed + seed-exchange
        ]
        ; Update the plant's seed bank
        set seed-bank seed-bank - seed-exchange
      ]
      print ( word "I now have " hiker-seed " seeds.")
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution to your problem

Yours is just a syntax problem: `of` requires that you place the reporter in square brackets ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of)).

In your case, it would be: `[seed-bank] of plants in-radius 1`.

### Other things

This was to solve your current problem. Let me note one more thing: you said you want this to happen "*when hikers move over a patch where a plant is*". Then know that `patches in-radius 1` is not the correct way to do it.

You can verify this by taking an empty environment and running

```
ask patch 0 0 [ask patches in-radius 1 [set pcolor green]]
```

in the Command Center. The result is:

[image]

which shows that `patches in-radius 1` are not just the initial patch of reference.
The primitive `patch-here` ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here)) is what a turtle needs to use to refer exactly and only to the patch it is standing on.

However, going one step forward: if you're interested in finding other agents that are standing on the same patch as the turtle running the command, you don't need to go through `patch-here`; the primitive `turtles-here` ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here)) exists, which can also be used with specific breeds - which is why Luke in his answer used `plants-here`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this context!! I wondered why Luke didn't include 'patches in-radius 1'.